# Can't grab the select element inside iframe in cypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress, cypress-iframe

I have a select element inside a iframe and need to select an option in a cypress test. But it doesn't find the element.
Here is the html:

```
<iframe id="KBasePopUp_frame_iframe" onload="KBasePopUp_frame.onIFrameLoaded(this)" scrolling="auto" width="550" height="230" frameborder="0" src="https://bmw-rsa-asd-int.kcenter.usu.com/knowledgebase/docCreate.do?ctrl.returnPage=closeInfoBoard.nav&amp;showMenu=false&amp;ctrl.nested=true&amp;appAreaId=f0d159c8-19e5-4a2a-825f-19fe4f553686&amp;query.docTypeClass=*&amp;categorySelection=on" style="height: 230px;" bis_size="{&quot;x&quot;:710,&quot;y&quot;:550,&quot;w&quot;:550,&quot;h&quot;:230,&quot;abs_x&quot;:710,&quot;abs_y&quot;:550}"></iframe>
```

and the select element is somewhere down below:

```
<select name="query.docTypeId" onchange="markDataChanged();" class="largeSelectBoxWarn" title="Mandatory field, please insert data!">
    <option value="4002" title="Automatic question">Automatic question</option><option value="3001" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</option>
    <option value="1" title="Problem">Problem</option>
    <option value="12" title="Solution">Solution</option>
</select>
```

I don't have access to the developer's code and can only inspect with web tools.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/

Comment: Donwvoted because you said "I already tried some of the common methods available on internet but nothing solved the problem" instead of explaining what you have tried. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ and https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) mentioned, interacting with an `iframe` [is described in Cypress's blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/).

You have to first retrieve the iframe document, and then its body, and then query from there.

```
const getIframeDocument = () => {
  return cy
  .get('#KBasePopUp_frame_iframe')
  // Cypress yields jQuery element, which has the real
  // DOM element under property "0".
  // From the real DOM iframe element we can get
  // the "document" element, it is stored in "contentDocument" property
  // Cypress "its" command can access deep properties using dot notation
  // https://on.cypress.io/its
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
}

const getIframeBody = () => {
  // get the document
  return getIframeDocument()
  // automatically retries until body is loaded
  .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
  // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
  // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
  .then(cy.wrap)
}

it('clicks the select option', () => {
    getIframeBody().find("select.largeSelectBoxWarn option[value=1]").click();
});
```

### Making it more flexible

The above is hard coded to your specific iframe since it's just supposed to teach you a concept. However, you could make it more flexible by accepting the query to the iframe as a parameter to `getIframeBody('#KBasePopUp_frame_iframe')`;

```
const getIframeDocument = (iframeQuery) => {
  return cy
  .get(iframeQuery)
  // Cypress yields jQuery element, which has the real
  // DOM element under property "0".
  // From the real DOM iframe element we can get
  // the "document" element, it is stored in "contentDocument" property
  // Cypress "its" command can access deep properties using dot notation
  // https://on.cypress.io/its
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
}

const getIframeBody = (iframeQuery) => {
  // get the document
  return getIframeDocument(iframeQuery)
  // automatically retries until body is loaded
  .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
  // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
  // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
  .then(cy.wrap)
}

it("clicks the select option n KBasePopUp iframe", () => {
  getIframeBody("KBasePopUp_frame_iframe").find("select.largeSelectBoxWarn option[value=1]").click();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this solution worked for one iframe but when I use the same technique for another iframe at a later stage in the same test, it can't find the element.

Comment: const iframeDocument = () => {
            return cy
            .get('iframe#KBasePopUp_frame_iframe')
            .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
        }
          
        const iframeBody = () => {
        return iframeDocument()
        .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
        .then(cy.wrap)
        }
          
        iframeBody().click()
        iframeBody().find('button[name="sendBtn4"]').click()

Comment: @Meenakshi Probably because your other iframe doesn't have an id of `#KBasePopUp_frame_iframe`? Please ask follow-up questions as a new question since your original question was fully answered. The `getIframeDocument` function I provided was almost copy/pasted from their examples and is not intended to be reused. You likely need to add a iFrameCssQuery parameter to  pass through to `getIframeDocument | getIframeBody`  and call it like `getIframeBody('selector of iframe').find('button[name="sendBtn4"]').click()`

Answer (score 1):

Despite explanations above, my test still used to fail.

Then according to [cypress blog about iframes](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress) I changed the two functions mentioned above into one and also set  `"chromeWebSecurity": false` config in cypress.config.js file and it worked. Maybe it could help someone!

```
const getIframeBody = () => {
  // get the iframe > document > body
  // and retry until the body element is not empty
  return cy
  .get('iframe[data-cy="the-frame"]')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
  // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
  // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
  .then(cy.wrap)
}

it('gets the post using single its', () => {
  cy.visit('index.html')
  getIframeBody().find('#run-button').should('have.text', 'Try it').click()
  getIframeBody().find('#result').should('include.text', '"delectus aut autem"')
})
```

Comment: For me it seemed to work by only replacing `.should('not.be.undefined')` with `.should('not.be.empty')`.